# Django manage.py error "bad interpreter: Permission denied" on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I have installed Django on Ubuntu 14.04 then I have activate the virtual environment and create an empty project and when I start the server everything is fine:

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I have then uploaded my "hello world" project with WinSCP (the project was developed with Visual Studio on Windows client), then I run the same command to start the server:

```
chmod +x manage.py
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Result:

```
: No such file or directory
```

The first line of manage.py is the same of the empty project, which run without any problem and is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I modified the first line of the manage.py to:

```
#!/django/projects/prj01/prj01env/bin python
```

At that point I run again manage.py and the error message is this:

```
bash: ./manage.py: /django/projects/prj01/prj01env/bin: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

I run every command as root.

Do you know how I can make my "hello world" project run properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the mistake:

1. I write back the initial code `#!/usr/bin/env python`
2. I run the command `dos2unix manage.py`

Now it is working fine.